# securing a samba server to work with windows 10 and linux at the highest possible smb protocoll with encryption

Tags: samba, samba4

i try to build a samba server for filesharing within my network. the main goal is a samba fileshare server with two shares (one "exchange" folder for guest access, writable, one folder "cifs" only accessible for user "cifs" with password, writeable) and the latest smb-protocol for use with linux and windows 8.1 and above, completly encrypted and signed.

i created this smb.conf for my needs:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
interfaces = eth0
bind interfaces only = yes
ntlm auth = yes

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level = 3
max log size = 1000
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

server role = standalone server
;passdb backend = tdbsam
;obey pam restrictions = yes

security = user
encrypt passwords = true
invalid users = root
map to guest = bad user
guest account = nobody
read only = yes
smb encrypt = mandatory
server signing = mandatory
client min protocol = SMB2_10
client max protocol = SMB3

[cifs]
   comment = CIFS-Share
   path = /disks/1TB/cifs/
   available = yes
   browseable = yes
   write list = cifs
   guest ok = yes
   create mode = 0754
   directory mode = 0755
   force create mode = 0754
   force directory mode = 0755

[exchange]
   comment = exchange folder
   path = /disks/2TB/exchange/
   available = yes
   browseable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   read only = no
```

my problem:
when i connect with a linux box, i cannot connect. it fails with errormessage

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Bad SMB2 signature for message
[0000] 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ........ ........
[0000] 1D 6E C7 C8 A5 07 23 F5   4E 9A DF 33 89 36 F7 89   .n....#. N..3.6..
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
```

command i used to connect:

```
smbclient -e //192.168.1.11/exchange --user=guest% -mSMB3
```

my environment:
lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:    9.5
Codename:   stretch

4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Problems:
at first, some cosmetics:
syslog is deprecated message: i removed the syslog entry in my config-file, but this notice still comes up.

second:
i cannot connect to the samba server with smbclient.
i can connect with nautilus with no errors. but: nothing is encrypted, nothing is signed. Protocol is NT1. I dont want anyone connect with old protocols. At least SMBv2_10 is mandatory.

smbstatus on the server results in:

```
Samba version 4.5.12-Debian
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
17140   -1           -1           testlinux (ipv4:192.168.6.12:44422)         NT1               -                    -                    
17140   nobody       nogroup      testlinux (ipv4:192.168.6.12:44422)         NT1               -                    -                    
17151   nobody       nogroup      192.168.6.12 (ipv4:192.168.6.12:37766)      NT1               -                    -                    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPC$         17140   testlinux      Tue Sep 11 10:42:34 2018 CEST    -            -           
exchange    17151   192.168.6.12   Tue Sep 11 10:42:37 2018 CEST    -            -
```